# Getting Magento to send email when a payment is received

Tags: magento

I don't believe Magento has an out of box method of sending an email to inform the owner when a payment has been received so is there any way that this can be programmed?

So far I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828781/magento-send-emails-for-different-order-status) but it looks like it might be more focused on sending the email to the customer instead of the vendor; and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365930/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-payment-received-in-magento) but apart from being completely lost ( as by the sound of it was the OP ) one person said accepted answer was a bit out of date and also I'm not sure it's what I need anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you need is (surprise) an observer module to do exactly that. Also, it is quite the same work [in one of the links you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365930/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-payment-received-in-magento).

To make a barebones observer module, you only need three files:

/app/etc/modules/Electricjesus_Notifyowner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Electricjesus_Notifyowner >
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Electricjesus/Notifyowner/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <notifyowner>
                <class>Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model</class>
            </notifyowner>
        </models>          
        <events>
                <sales_order_payment_pay>
                    <observers>
                        <notifyOwnerEvent>
                                <class>notifyowner/observer</class>
                                <method>notifyOwnerEvent</method>
                        </notifyOwnerEvent>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_payment_pay >     
        </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Electricjesus/Notifyowner/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model_Observer
{
    public function notifyOwnerEvent($observer)
    {

        // parameters you can get from the $observer parameter:
        // array(’payment’ ? $this, ‘invoice’ ? $invoice)

        $payment = $observer->getPayment();
        $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();

        // derivative data
        $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order

        $ownerEmail = 'owner@shop.com';
        /*
             - build data
             - build email structure
             - send email via any php mailer method you want
        */
        return $this;  // always return $this.
    }

}
```

You can also use other events in place of `sales_order_payment_pay` (see config.xml). See [this list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events) for a semi-complete list of events along with their parameters. And on [this document](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method#list_of_events) to is some techniques to check/get an update of the current list of events with their parameters.

I recommend using Zend_Mail to do your mail stuff inside the observer. Nothing special, I'm just biased towards Zend stuff.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

--- EDIT

if you want a ready-made extension to do this (and more) and if you do not mind paying for it, you can take a look at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-email-notifications.html

Comment: Thanks, I'd say turning that barebones observer into a working piece of production code could take a fair bit of time that my client will possibly not want to pay for. Do you know if there is a plugin available as I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.